# how to remove character from array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array snapshot

```
Array(
        [created_at] => 2014-02-18T08:29:33.388Z
        [modified_at] => 2014-02-18T12:44:46.011Z
      )
```

1. I have to remove character from `[created]` array  and `[modified_at]`, how should I resolve this issue?
2. I want like : `[created_at] =>2014-02-18 8:29:33`
3. secondly like : `[modified_at] =>2014-02-18  12:44:46`

How to resolve this issue? Data is in form of `json` , I have tried this code:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', "_", $aba);
```

whats is correct method to resolve this issue.

Comment: The code you have tried is completely irrelevant to the problem. Do you really want to "replace anything that's not a letter or number with underscore"? Not according to your question!

Comment: i want like  2014-02-18 8:29:33 from [created_at] => 2014-02-18T08:29:33.388Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look this

```
 $str = "2014-02-18T08:29:33.388Z";
   $nstr = preg_replace('/\.([0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z])$/', "", $str);
   echo preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z]/', " ", $nstr);
```

OUTPUT:  2014-02-18 08:29:33

Comment: thanks deepus it  but output  is : 2014-02-18T08:29:33 , i want to remove to .

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary to use regex, just re format the date string.

Example:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, array('created_at', 'modified_at'))) {
        $arr[$key] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($value));
    }
}
```

Comment: That brings in extra overhead (converting a string to a timestamp with strtotime and then back again with date) just to manipulate the string values and as such doesn't address the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

To do strictly what you want, which is string manipulation (of strings which just happen to represent date/timestamps):

```
$t = Array (
    'created_at' => '2014-02-18T08:29:33.388Z',
    'modified_at' => '2014-02-18T12:44:46.011Z'
);

$r = array();
foreach ($t as $key => $element) {
    $r[$key] = str_replace('T', ' ', str_replace('Z', '', $element));

}


var_dump($r);
```

This doesn't have the overhead of converting strings to datestamps and back again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/([0-9\-]+)[^0-9]*?([0-9\:]+).*/', '$1 $2', $array['created_at']);
```

will give you:

```
2014-02-18 12:44:46
2014-02-18 08:29:33
```

Comment: thanks manu it worked , but could u help right site and book way learn regex

Comment: Look at the question: [Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)